# I can't make the last line spread across in my display

Tags: python, scheduler, display, show

I have the following code to print a schedule from inputs but can't make the last line spread under the like the header does.

My showRecord code is as follows...

```
Class Appointment:
    def __str__(appt):
        return f'{appt.date} {appt.start} {appt.end} {appt.description} {appt.venue} {appt.priority}'
```

OTHER CODE UNTIL

```
def showRecords(schedule):
    print('{:<15}{:<10}{:<8}{:<25}{:<25}{:<10}'.format("Date","Start","End","Subject","Venue","Priority")) # '<' here aligns text to left
    print('{:<15}{:<10}{:<8}{:<25}{:<25}{:<10}'.format("----","-----","---","-------","-----","--------"))
    for appointment in schedule:
        print(appointment)
    else:
        print("No more appointments found.")
```

I have tried the following

```
print('{:<15}{:<10}{:<8}{:<25}{:<25}{:<10}'.format(schedule))
```

...and...

```
print('{:<15}{:<10}{:<8}{:<13}{:<11}{:<10}'.format(date, start, end, description, venue, priority))
```

but the last line just bunches up as follows...

[image]

I've tried several codes as noted above and can't make it work. Please help.

NOTE: I've added the rest of the code!

Comment: The last line looks ok, only the three lines with appointment data look weird (because the f-string doesn't contain format specifiers).

Comment: I'm new to Python and don't quite get what you mean. How would I fix the line that won't spread the last result line?

Comment: I've added the rest of the code above.

Comment: In `Appointment.__str__` replace the `return f'{appt.date}...` by `return f'{appt.date:<15}...` and similarly for the following fields in this line.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Then the string representation will always have that alignment and padding. Which is not what `__str__` should be concerned with. It's the wrong place to make these changes.

Comment: @MatBailie Right. I tend to quick and dirty answers sometimes.

Comment: It's ok, I actually got what I needed from your answer so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just rely on `__str__`, because it (correctly) doesn't have any padding or alignment codes in the string formatting.

Nor can you rely on the padding and alignment of the headers, because that's only for the headers.

So, if you want to pad and align the text representation of an appointment, you have to do it yourself. By adding the padding and alignment formatting codes to the string being formatted and printed...

```
def showRecords(schedule):
    print('{:<15}{:<10}{:<8}{:<25}{:<25}{:<10}'.format("Date","Start","End","Subject","Venue","Priority")) # '<' here aligns text to left
    print('{:<15}{:<10}{:<8}{:<25}{:<25}{:<10}'.format("----","-----","---","-------","-----","--------"))
    for appt in schedule:
        print(f'{appt.date:<15}{appt.start:<10}{appt.end:<8}{appt.description:<25}{appt.venue:<25}{appt.priority:<10}')
    else:
        print("No more appointments found.")
```